# jpa create duplicate entity

Tags: jpa, duplicates

I am wondering why my Code does not duplicate my entry each time I run the program. What Code is responsible for checking it? Is it maybe because of my persistence.xml file?

```
@Table(name ="benutzer", catalog = "dbwebanw_sose15_03")
@SecondaryTable(name="benutzerdaten",
    pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "benutzer_id"))
public class Benutzer {



private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String passwort;
private byte istAdministrator;



public Benutzer() {

}

public Benutzer(String name, String email, String passwort, byte istAdministrator) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.passwort = passwort;
    this.istAdministrator = istAdministrator;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "benutzer_id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Column(table="benutzerdaten",name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Column(name="email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}


@Column(table="benutzerdaten",name = "passwort")
public String getPasswort() {
    return passwort;
}

public void setPasswort(String passwort) {
    this.passwort = passwort;
}


@Column(table="benutzerdaten")
public byte getIstAdministrator() {
    return istAdministrator;
}

public void setIstAdministrator(byte istAdministator) {
    this.istAdministrator = istAdministator;
}
}
```

Here you can see my Main program:

```
public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

    EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnit");

            EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
    entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

    Benutzer benutzer = new Benutzer("Mahmut Demir", "bemut@web.de", "meric",(byte)1);


    entitymanager.persist( benutzer );

    entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

    entitymanager.close( );
    emfactory.close( );
}
}
```

Comment: `@id` probably creates a unique primary key, so you're essentially overwriting it.

Comment: Your code is incomplete: `"Holland", Date.valueOf("2006-08-31") );`. And you should add your `persistence.xml`, if you think that this is your problem. If you use `create` for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, than this would always recreate your database.

Comment: I forgot to delete this line. '"Holland", Date.valueOf("2006-08-31") );' And yes, I use 'create'.

Comment: but when I use `update`, it makes a new entity with the identical data, every time I run the main.